"UbershaderProvider" giving error "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError" in android studio project
I have an app and tried to launch an 3D scene via Filament to show a 3D model at the center of the screen, but when I tried to execute it, the app crashed and gave me the error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError.
I have imported com.google.android.filament.gltfio.UbershaderProvider and synced my gradle.kts and APK properly.
I tried to use Filament inside @compose.
I'm an student and not really familiar using Filament nor Android Studio.
Here's the part that uses UbershaderProvider:
@Composable
fun WardrobeView(onButtonClick: () -> Unit) {
    System.loadLibrary("filament-jni")

    var showDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val context = LocalContext.current

    // Create a SurfaceView
    val surfaceView = remember {SurfaceView(context) }
    // Initialize Filament
    Filament.init()
    val engine = remember { Engine.create() }
    val view = engine.createView()
    val camera = engine.createCamera()
    // Set the camera to look at the origin
    camera.lookAt(0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

    // Set the view to use the camera
    view.camera = camera


    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        val engine = Engine.create()
        val assetLoader = AssetLoader(engine, UbershaderProvider(engine), EntityManager.get())

        // Launching a coroutine within LaunchedEffect
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // Assuming readAsset returns ByteBuffer directly, adjust accordingly if it's different
            val assetBytes = readAsset(context, "")
            val asset: FilamentAsset? = assetLoader.createAsset(assetBytes)

            // Use withContext to switch back to the Main dispatcher for UI updates or Filament operations that require it
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                asset?.let {
                    // Assuming there's a function or method to add entities to the scene and handle rendering
                    // This is also the place to handle any UI updates or operations that depend on the asset being loaded
                }
                // Don't forget to destroy the assetLoader and its assets when done
                asset?.releaseSourceData()
                assetLoader.destroy()
            }
        }
    }

I tried to make a scene where I displayed a 3D model using Jetpack Compose and Filament as the engine.
